# ClassNotFoundException "android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier$Builder"

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am working on a flutter plugin that connects to specific wifi. Since my `targetSdkVersion` is `29` and `WifiConfiguuration` class is deprecated and I can't even use a few methods of `WifiManager` class so I have to use `WifiNetworkSpecifier`. 
Now the problem is that the application is running fine on Android 10 (checked on Realme RMX1851, Redmi Note 8 Pro) but it is not working on Android 6.0 (Vivo v5). I am getting ClassNotFoundException and then the app crashes, here's my code:-

```
 void connect() {
    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        result.error("WIFI_TURNED_OFF", "Wifi Adapter is Offline", "Please Turn on the wifi adapter");
        return;
    }

    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsidPattern(new PatternMatcher(ssid, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX))
            .setWpa2Passphrase(password);
    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

    NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier.toString());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
    }

    NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm != null) {
        cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                Log.e("WIFIDelegate", "available");
                super.onAvailable(network);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                Log.e("WIFIDelegate", "Not available");
                super.onUnavailable();
            }
        });
       } else {

        result.error("Connectivity_Manager_Not_Available", "Connectivity Manager is not available", "Connectivity Manager is not available");
    }
```

And the error is

````
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier$Builder;
E/flutter (18197):  at com.akaalapps.wifi_connect.WifiDelegate.connect(WifiDelegate.java:47)
E/flutter (18197):  at com.akaalapps.wifi_connect.WifiConnectPlugin.connectToWifi(WifiConnectPlugin.java:177)
E/flutter (18197):  at com.akaalapps.wifi_connect.WifiConnectPlugin.onMethodCall(WifiConnectPlugin.java:78)
E/flutter (18197):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
E/flutter (18197):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/flutter (18197):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/flutter (18197):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (18197):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
E/flutter (18197):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/flutter (18197):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5790)
E/flutter (18197):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (18197):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
E/flutter (18197):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
E/flutter (18197): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.akaalapps.wifi_connect_example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.akaalapps.wifi_connect_example-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.akaalapps.wifi_connect_example-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
E/flutter (18197):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/flutter (18197):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/flutter (18197):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/flutter (18197):  ... 13 more
E/flutter (18197):  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier$Builder
E/flutter (18197):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/flutter (18197):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/flutter (18197):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/flutter (18197):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/flutter (18197):      ... 14 more
E/flutter (18197):  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
E/flutter (18197): 
F/flutter (18197): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
F/libc    (18197): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 18197 (connect_example)
Lost connection to device.```
````

Comment: `WifiNetworkSpecifier` is new to Android 10. You cannot use it on older devices. You will need to us different code on those older devices, and use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to decide which set of code to use on the current device.

Comment: So that means I can still use deprecated classes with proper conditions provided using ```Build.VERSION.SDK_INT```. Right?

Comment: Yes. In many cases, you can use deprecated methods on newer versions of Android too. Usually, "deprecated" means "we have something else that we would prefer that you use". In your case, IIRC, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 29 or higher, the older methods no longer work. So, it would be safer for you to limit your use of those older methods to the older devices.